# Mobile data still being used despite restricting access to Mobile data in Settings

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an app for a client and am experiencing an issue where the app is still using mobile data on my device, even though I have mobile data turned OFF for the mobile app, and wi-fi is switched OFF also.

The app is a video-calling app, using WebRTC, Sockets (socket.io) and usual API calls. All of these are still being used and successfully returning data, meaning a fully-fledged video call is working, despite the wi-fi being disabled and mobile data being restricted too.

I'd obviously like to resolve this situation, as I fear the app could be rejected by Apple upon submission.

The same experience occurs regardless of whether the device is connected to USB or not.

Only Airplane mode seems to provide the correct 'no connectivity' experience.

Comment: Why don't you try reachability library.Start any video session after checking connectivity by using reachability library.

Comment: I'm using Reachability library, but it responds as 'ReachableViaWWAN' as it's just sending out a data packet, not waiting for a response. Besides, it still doesn't change the fact that network calls are being made despite Wi-Fi & Mobile data being turned off.